# Can we attach a label to GitHub pull request, if build/status check is fine?

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

I have a situation, where i need to attach already created label ("Verified Build") to the Pull Request, if build/status check for that PR is green/fine.

Steps:

- User created a PR
- Started Build/Status check
- if check is fine, add label as ("Verified Build")
- If check is failing, add label as ("Build Failed")

I have gone through the documentation but couldn't find proper answer for the problem.
Can someone please help on this?

Comment: [`pascalgn/size-label-action`](https://github.com/pascalgn/size-label-action) does smth like that

Comment: You could look into the `status` and `check_suite` events, and attach a label for example using the GitHub CLI in a `run:` step with `gh pr edit --add-label`